# Batch to Remove files in a Folders of Different Users

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I remove files of a Folders for Different USers with a batch file?. For example:

```
C:\Documents and Setting\UserA\Folder1\file.abc
C:\Documents and Setting\UserB\Folder1\file.abc
C:\Documents and Setting\UserC\Folder1\file.abc
C:\Documents and Setting\UserD\Folder1\file.abc
C:\Documents and Setting\UserE\Folder1\file.abc
```

I want to remove the file.abc of every FOLDER1 of Every User. Every User has the same folder (Folder1) but they also have more Folders that I dont want to remove. At the end the files must be like this.

```
    C:\Documents and Setting\UserA\Folder1\
    C:\Documents and Setting\UserB\Folder1\
    C:\Documents and Setting\UserC\Folder1\
    C:\Documents and Setting\UserD\Folder1\
    C:\Documents and Setting\UserE\Folder1\
```

I really hope you can help me with this.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /d /r %%a in (*) do del "%%~a\Folder1\file.abc" 2>nul
```

Comment: Execute this from "C:\Documents and Settings" in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "C:\Documents and Settings"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b') do del %%a\Folder1\file.abc
```

This will look for `Folder1\file.abc` in every folder under `Documents and Settings`.  If you want to do this outside a batch file, change `%%a` to just `%a`.